Multiple Imputation method in RCT
We decided to use the multiple imputation method in a RCT to solve the problem of some follow-up missing data (for completely random reasons). I was planning on using the Multiple Imputation method with SPSS, which by default runs 5 iterations. My question is: are these 5 iterations enough in this case? Does anyone have experience with this? I have never done this before and am not very confident.
Thanks in advance!

Rubin made his recommendation based on relative efficiency, i.e. how well the imputation variance is approximated:

This is often the source for $m=5$ being "enough". Subsequent studies have demonstrated that this might not always be true, however. Everything will depend on the fraction of missing information $\gamma_0$, which is not necessarily equal to but often taken for the proportion of missing observations.

Graham et al. used a 1% power falloff tolerance in hypothesis tests, which required $m=20$ for $\gamma_0=0.3$, $m=40$ for $\gamma_0=0.5$, and $m=100$ or more for $\gamma_0\ge 0.7$.
Bodner determined that for a 95% CI half-width to be within 10% of its true value with 95% confidence requires $m=24$ for $\gamma_0=0.3$, $m=59$ for $\gamma_0=0.5$, and $m=114$ for $\gamma_0=0.7$.
Von Hippel illustrated that Rubin's suggestion produces only reliable point estimates at best, whereas significant sampling variability remains for standard errors and P-values. He, as well as White et al., recommends using the percentage of missing observations for $m$ as a rule of thumb instead.

In summary you probably want more than 5 imputations, they are much cheaper computationally than they were in 1987 anyway. In my experience there's little to gain above $m=100$ for reasonable fractions of missing information. You can only get an exact answer by doing multiple rounds of multiple imputation, determining the sampling variability, and calibrating that against your tolerance threshold for the statistic of interest.
(I'm more of a SAS user, this is all explained quite nicely in the documentation of PROC MI)

Use a full likelihood method fr analyzing longitudinal data and don't impute the outcome data.  E.g. GLS, mixed effects models, Bayesian longitudinal models.
